# Make JAWS announce unfocused element respecting its role

Tags: autocomplete, focus, jaws-screen-reader

I am looking for a way to make **JAWS** (and probably other screen readers) announce the unfocused element. I am having a `contenteditable` area which after typing certain characters opens autocomplete/suggestion panel. The focus stays inside `contenteditable` to enable further typing while the panel is open showing possible suggestion. The **JAWS** does not announce the panel appearance because it is not focused.
If the focus is forced on the panel **JAWS** announces it correctly (`role="listbox"`) but of course it breaks the autocomplete functionality.

I created a very simple sample which illustrates the problem:

```js
var editable = document.querySelector('#editable'),
  list = document.querySelector('#list'),
  counter = 0;

editable.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
  counter++;
  if (counter > 5) {
    list.style.display = 'block';
    list.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
    // Focusing list works fine and JAWS announces everything correctly, but then the contenteditable loses focus and typing cannot be continued which is crucial for autocompleting functionality.
    setTimeout( function() { list.focus() }, 0 ); // Comment out this line to see/hear the difference.
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.autocomplete_panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  border-bottom-color: #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}

#label_00 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="application">

  <div contenteditable="true" id="editable">
    Type sth to show panel...
  </div>

  <ul id="list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="label_00" class="autocomplete_panel" style="z-index: 9997; left: 150px; top: 20px;">
    <li data-id="1" role="option" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="4">Item 1</li>
    <li data-id="2" role="option" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="4">Item 2</li>
    <li data-id="3" role="option" aria-posinset="3" aria-setsize="4">Item 3</li>
    <li data-id="4" role="option" aria-posinset="4" aria-setsize="4">Item 4</li>
    <li aria-hidden="true" id="label_00">Autosuggestion panel</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

JSfiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/f1ames/op15mm8z/.

**Some solutions I am considering but are not perfect:**

1. Use hidden span with `aria-live` and dynamic text (with similar/same text to native **JAWS** announcement):

   - inconsistency between screen readers (different announcements for `listbox` in different screen readers)
   - won't be based on screen reader language (it should)
   - not flexible (JAWS may have different setting so announcements may vary -  native JAWS announcement would be much better)
2. Focusing autocomplete panel:

   - should still support typing inside `contenteditable` which may be very tricky especially for some unicode characters and composition
   - when focus gets back to `contenteditable` the announcement of autocomplete will be aborted
3. Providing **aria-markup** to make JAWS properly announce autocomplete panel:

   - `aria-live` and `aria-atomic` works to some extend but the `role` is not supported. **JAWS** reads only `aria-labelledby` element or list items as plain text (difference for `aria-atomic='true/false'`)

So at the moment I am not aware of any method to make **JAWS** announce the unfocused element same way as if it was focused. Any thoughts?

Btw. aria practices for autocomplete: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two aria attributes to achieve this.
1. aria-owns
   This attribute should have id of the list box, which should have role="listbox"
2. aria-activedescendant
   This attribute should have id of the list item inside the list box, which should have role="option"

**Sample Code:**
https://github.com/senthilshanmugam/a11yTypeAhead
**Demo:**
http://a11ywidgetsdemo.azurewebsites.net/#/a11yTypeAhead



In the below code sample, the attribute, aria-owns is having the id (**AutoSuggestion-list**) of the list box with role="listbox" and aria-activedescendant is having the id (**AutoSuggestion-item-1**) of the list item inside the list box with role="option".  This item is the currently selected item as indicated by class="selected" attribute

When the user changes the selection the value in aria-activedescendant should point to the appropriate id of the list item, say **AutoSuggestion-item-2**

```
<input id="auto-complete" type="text" aria-expanded="true" 
  aria-labelledby="List-label" aria-owns="AutoSuggestion-list" 
  aria-activedescendant="AutoSuggestion-item-1">

<ul id="AutoSuggestion-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox">
  <li id="AutoSuggestion-item-0" role="option" aria-label="Malaysia">Malaysia</li>
  <li id="AutoSuggestion-item-1" role="option" class="selected" aria-label="Maldives">Maldives</li>
  <li id="AutoSuggestion-item-2" role="option" aria-label="Myanmar (Burma)">Myanmar (Burma)</li>
  <li id="AutoSuggestion-item-3" role="option" aria-label="Oman">Oman</li>
</ul>
```